How to iterate through a list by hosts, not by items?
I have the following Ansible playbook (im using 2.9.21), which is working perfectly fine, just as I want it to work:
- name: Sync package_00 package to the remote hosts
  ansible.builtin.synchronize:
    src: /home/ansible/files/package_00
    dest: /tmp/
    recursive: false
    archive: false
    checksum: true
    delete: false

- name: Sync package_01 package to the remote hosts
  ansible.builtin.synchronize:
    src: /home/ansible/files/package_01
    dest: /tmp/
    recursive: false
    archive: false
    checksum: true
    delete: false

- name: Sync package_02 package to the remote hosts
  ansible.builtin.synchronize:
    src: /home/ansible/files/package_02
    dest: /tmp/
    recursive: false
    archive: false
    checksum: true
    delete: false

It correctly grabs the first task and copies the first file package_00 to all the hosts specified. As soon as it is ready with the first file, it starts the second file.
Now, since I have a huge number of files and the above mentioned example is quite ugly it would be nice to have some loop or with_items solution, but unfortunately I was unable to achieve the exact same functionality as described. Whenever I change to something like this, the execution is completely different:
- name: Sync the packages to the remote host
  ansible.builtin.synchronize:
    src: /home/ansible/files/package_{{ item }}
    dest: /tmp/
    recursive: false
    archive: false
    checksum: true
    delete: false
  loop: "{{ range(0, 100) | list }}"

Now Ansible tries to copy all the files to the first host, and all the files to the second host, and so on.
I have tried to experiment with loop, with_items, serial keyword, but no luck.

Hi. grabs the first task and copies the first file package_00 to all the hosts specified. As soon as it is ready with the first file, it starts the second file. vs copy all the files to the first host, and all the files to the second host, and so on I do not understand, so it is the same. What is the difference? Related https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html

Thank you for your question: In the first example Ansible copies the files in a serialized manner, just as I want. It does not start the second file until I have the first on every host. But in the second example it copies all files to the host on which it is working currently.

@Andrew, so - do I understand correctly that you want Ansible to continue copying the next files without waiting for other hosts?

@AlexanderPletnev, no, quite the opposite, I want to copy the first file to all the hosts. As soon as the first file is finished copy the second file to all the hosts. Afterwards the third file, and so on for tens or hundreds of files.

Just curious - could you please describe the use case? I mean, the rationale behind the desired logic? Cause I'd likely second the @U880D's note on avoiding this.

Sure, gladly: I have multiple thousands of servers where I have to copy files. The problem is that the bandwidth is really limited, and I can not even use the full capacity for a long time since it might cause business disruptions. Moreover the bandwidth is hugely different on every host, but I have to copy the files as fast as possible (over a few days tops). The idea came that if I use timeslotting like this and use small sized chunks using the full bandwith only for a couple of minutes on every host it might be fine from business perspective and it would be as fast as possible on 50 threads

@AlexanderPletnev If you have a better idea to achieve this scenario under the constraints im facing please do not hesitate to share. Thank you guys again for the help! :)

With significant overhead, decreased performance and increased runtime, the following minimal example show how to achieve such behavior.
Inventory example.ini
[managed]
remote.example.com
managed.example.com
external.example.com

Task file debug.yml
  - name: "Loop included {{ item }}"
    debug:
      msg: "package_{{ ansible_loop.index0 }}"

Playbook main.yml
---
- hosts: managed
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: Loop directly
      debug:
        msg: "package_{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ range(0, 3) | list }}"

    - name: Include
      include_tasks:
        file: debug.yml
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true

Called via
ansible-playbook --inventory example.ini main.yml

Resulted output and runtime
PLAY [managed] *****************************************************************************************************
Friday 04 October 2024  18:46:44 +0200 (0:00:00.027)       0:00:00.027 ********

TASK [Loop directly] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [remote.example.com] => (item=0) =>
  msg: package_0
ok: [remote.example.com] => (item=1) =>
  msg: package_1
ok: [remote.example.com] => (item=2) =>
  msg: package_2
ok: [managed.example.com] => (item=0) =>
  msg: package_0
ok: [managed.example.com] => (item=1) =>
  msg: package_1
ok: [external.example.com] => (item=0) =>
  msg: package_0
ok: [managed.example.com] => (item=2) =>
  msg: package_2
ok: [external.example.com] => (item=1) =>
  msg: package_1
ok: [external.example.com] => (item=2) =>
  msg: package_2
Friday 04 October 2024  18:46:44 +0200 (0:00:00.065)       0:00:00.093 ********

TASK [Include] *****************************************************************************************************
included: debug.yml for remote.example.com, managed.example.com, external.example.com => (item=remote.example.com)
included: debug.yml for remote.example.com, managed.example.com, external.example.com => (item=managed.example.com)
included: debug.yml for remote.example.com, managed.example.com, external.example.com => (item=external.example.com)
Friday 04 October 2024  18:46:45 +0200 (0:00:00.048)       0:00:00.141 ********

TASK [Loop included remote.example.com] ****************************************************************************
ok: [remote.example.com] =>
  msg: package_0
ok: [managed.example.com] =>
  msg: package_0
ok: [external.example.com] =>
  msg: package_0
Friday 04 October 2024  18:46:45 +0200 (0:00:00.037)       0:00:00.179 ********

TASK [Loop included managed.example.com] ***************************************************************************
ok: [remote.example.com] =>
  msg: package_1
ok: [managed.example.com] =>
  msg: package_1
ok: [external.example.com] =>
  msg: package_1
Friday 04 October 2024  18:46:45 +0200 (0:00:00.036)       0:00:00.215 ********

TASK [Loop included external.example.com] **************************************************************************
ok: [remote.example.com] =>
  msg: package_2
ok: [managed.example.com] =>
  msg: package_2
ok: [external.example.com] =>
  msg: package_2

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
external.example.com       : ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
managed.example.com        : ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
remote.example.com         : ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
Friday 04 October 2024  18:46:45 +0200 (0:00:00.067)       0:00:00.283 ********
===============================================================================
Loop included external.example.com --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.07s
Loop directly ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 0.07s
Include ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 0.05s
Loop included remote.example.com ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.04s
Loop included managed.example.com ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.04s

Please take note that

"...since I have a huge number of files ... achieve the exact same functionality as described."

that should be avoided and you should overthink your Use Case.

Thank you @U880D it is working perfectly!
